# Sdl.init throws an exception

Tags: ocaml, sdl-2

I would like to use SDL2 library functions in Ocaml. I have sdl2 and ocamlsdl2 installed, but calling `Sdl.init` throws an exception.

On utop

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "sdl2";;
Sdl.init [`VIDEO];;
```

Gives an error of `Exception: Failure "Sdl.init"`

Comment: This looks to be a problem arising at the level of the c ffi (see https://github.com/fccm/OCamlSDL2/blob/0cd32260f686c8ef875b43fa7e61710ad0c2645a/src/sdlinit_stub.c#L56). This isn't a user friendly failure, obviously. If I where you, I'd probably submit an issue to the ocamlsdl2 repo.

Answer (score 1):

The documentations and the tutorials about SDL2 tell that you should use the function SDL_GetError(), or in ocaml Sdlerror.get_error, to know what is the error encountered:
https://fccm.github.io/OCamlSDL2/Sdlerror.html#VALget_error

Comment: Do you have any association with this github project? If so, you should disclose it so you aren't mistaken with a spammer (given that your username is in the github link).

Comment: Yes, I am the author of the bindings. Sorry English is not my born language, what does it mean: "you should disclose it" ?

Comment: That just means somewhere in the post it helps to say "I wrote this" or "I am affiliated with this project". I went ahead and suggested an edit for you :)